# Python Regex for preposition in sentence

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string

I have a sentence that has a preposition or preposition in a word and I want to separate the words "di" and "ke" a sentence.

Code in this [link](https://regex101.com/r/NOdmfp/1)

```py
sentence = "kemana dimanake di daladi dipukul ke situ"
regex_patern = r"^(di)|(ke)"
```

the sentence I want is

```py
result= "ke mana di manake di daladi di pukul ke situ"
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to match either `ke` or `di` followed by asserting a position where a word boundary  does not match `\B`.

```
(?:ke|di)\B
```

You could prepend the pattern using a word boundary `\b(?:ke|di)\B` if ke or di should not be part of a [longer word](https://regex101.com/r/ZYoTbS/3).

Then replace with the full match followed by a space:

`\g<0>`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZYoTbS/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/uUaJ16)

For example

```
import re

sentence = "kemana dimanake di daladi dipukul ke situ"
regex_patern = r"(?:ke|di)\B"
print(re.sub(regex_patern, r"\g<0> ", sentence))
```

Result

> ke mana di manake di daladi di pukul ke situ

If you want to make the match a bit broader, you could also use a positive lookahead `(?=\S)` asserting what is on the right is a non whitespace char.

```
(?:ke|di)(?=\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZYoTbS/2)

Comment: Why not ^ in regex pattern ?

Comment: @AlhamsyaBintangDyasta `^` Asserts the start of the string, and in your example data `di` should match on multiple places.

Comment: @AlhamsyaBintangDyasta: is it possible to have words that starts with "ke" or "di"?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte You are right, I've added that to the answer.

Comment: If I need a limit of each word, how?

Comment: @Thefourthbird check again [link](https://regex101.com/r/ZYoTbS/4) i hope 
```python
result "ke mana di manake di daladi di pukul ke situ diem"
```

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte i want limit word